# Pretest-Posttest comparison

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, covariance, ancova, paired-comparisons

I am having a hard time doing this on Stata.
I have a group of 32 students.  All perform a pretest and are scored.  Next, half of them are randomized to receiving an intervention and the other half don't receive it.  Next, all are brought back after 1 week to perform a post-test and are scored.

I know that it is wrong to compare post-test scores with a t-test between intervention and control groups.  Apparently I have to do this with "adjusting for baseline" and online I think this has to do with an ANCOVA approach.

Can someone please assist me with getting the code?  I'm not sure how to do this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a really great resource that will help you take you through deciding which test to use and how to execute the code:

http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/whatstat/

Outside of your question, I think you might be looking for a repeated measures design, like a repeated measures or mixed AVOVA. If the pre-test is measuring the 'same thing' as the post-test, I think that would fit one of those approaches better.
If, on the other hand, the pre-test is measuring an separate variable to control for in a later analysis, another approach might be appropriate.